# How to keep cache_form small

Tags: caching, database, theming, forms

I have noticed in mysql that cache_form.MYD table is 14GB. Why did it grow so big? Is it safe to empty it? and how can I avoid this happening in the future?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Drupal?

Comment: It is drupal 6.22

Comment: this question duplicates "Cache Form table size is enormous" - https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/260649/53059 - a question that is a little newer and has much more activity/information

Answer (score 8):

This is a known issue in Drupal 6 and 7 for that matter. It is not cleared when running cron. You can safely delete all rows that has expired.

```
DELETE FROM {cache_form} WHERE expire < now();
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Since it's a "known issue", do you have a link to the issue queue?

Comment: @marcvangend Search in Drupal with cache form table size, many have reported that this particular table takes more than a gig some times.

Comment: I know how searching works, and I know there are a many of pages all over the web about this and similar problems. But I'm not asking for many... my question is, if anyone has a link to a single issue where developers are actively working on solving this specific problem.

Comment: @marcvangend I didnt mean like that , please dont take it that way. I just thought that you are nt aware of this issue :) There was one issue which was active but I didnt see any positive outcomes from it, same issue is still there.

Comment: @marcvangend: Well, there is many issue tickets on this: https://drupal.org/project/issues/drupal?text=cache_form&status=All. I have created a module https://drupal.org/sandbox/roheim/2010918 yesterday to deal with it. If you need it for D6, tell me. And bugs, feature requests of course as normal. I hope to make this a full project after some people have used it a little.

Comment: I'm partial to agree with @marcvangend, if there is a "this is a know issue", then please link to the issue directly, the search doesn't help narrow the problem down and if you have a particular problem I'm sure cross posting the issue from the drupal issue queue can help us narrow in on the problem at hand.

Answer (score 8):

https://drupal.org/project/optimizedb - module that will solve your problem. He can clear the table cache_form by Cron, also perform optimization and more. Versions available for Drupal 6.7.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that cron isn't running on your site.  I am not 100% positive about that particular table, but other cache tables do get stale entries removed when cron runs.

If you need help setting up cron, peruse http://drupal.org/cron

Comment: Well, as I see the status report the cron is run 1 hour ago.

Comment: How old is your site?  Forms API had a bug, but I thought it was fixed a while ago: http://drupal.org/node/230374  If you clear your cache manually, does that table still grow w/o bound?

Comment: The site is quite old but all modules are up to date. I'll empty the table and will see. Thanks